# KNN Over 2 PySpark Dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two PySpark dataframes. They look something like this:

```
df1 = 
[Row(itemA='1', values=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2]),
Row(itemA='2', values=[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]),
Row(itemA='3', values=[0.8, 0.1, 0.1])]

df2 = 
[Row(itemB='1', values=[1,2,3]),
Row(itemB='2', values=[1,3,6]),
Row(itemC='3', values=[8,1,1])]
```

So here each item is represented by a 3 point vector. I want to return a new dataframe where we have itemA and the top 2 most similar items from df2 using cosine similarity.

```
Ex: Row(itemA='1', values=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2], similar=[("1",[1,2,3]),("2",[1,3,6]))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. You need to join the dataframes somehow and put one frame into the UDF.